# python , pandas - better way to count columns with smaller value than other column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table ( [table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhMEL.png)  ), and i want to check how many values from columns  0:5 , 
are smaller than the 6th column and insert this number to a new column.

this is the way i did it :

```
seg['LargerThanLastMonth']  = seg.apply(
    lambda x : x[0:5].lt(x['sgmntlnMnt 201810']).sum(),
    axis=1
)
```

it is working   ,
but im looking for a better way and maybe a way without using the explicit name for the 6th column and

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lt`

```
df['new']=df.iloc[:,:5].lt(df.iloc[:,5],0).sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use numpy:

```
df['new'] = np.sum(df.iloc[:,:5] < df.iloc[:,5], axis=1)
```